# Cron job not working properly when automatically executed

Tags: php, cron

I can't make my SQL backup cron job works with this line:

```
$server   = 'localhost';
$database = 'xxx';
$user     = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';

exec("mysqldump --user=".$user." --password=".$password." --host=".$server." ".$database." > _files/db.sql");
```

This directory `_files` is in the same directory as my .php file.

When I execute it directly from the browser, it works.

But when I execute it with the cron job (each day at 3AM), it's not working:

The cron job is the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/persxxxx/public_html/www/xxxxxxxxx/_new/assets/app/php/cron/adm_daily_backup.php
```

In the `adm_daily_backup.php` I have others task executed during the cron job, and these others works perfectly...

Where is the error ?

Comment: In your mysqldump command, use the full path to your backup dir.

Comment: As starting point: escape shell arguments and don't rely on current working directory.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, it was the problem. Thanks.